# I am not being able to open terminal in webstorm application

Tags: webstorm

Webstorm can't open terminal!

I am currently using this shell path:

```
bash.exe --login
```

I have also used the below one:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe -login -i
```

But it wasnt of any help.

Comment: What is your IDE version exactly?

Comment: Accordingly to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135265 (which duplicates another ticket) it was fixed back in January so all current versions should have it working.